# Umbraco on Azure - Web Role Package Upload

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to work through this tutorial to set up an Umbraco site on Azure:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/584908/Umbrazure-Limitless-Websites-with-Umbraco-on-Azure

I get to the point where the package uploads to the web role.

When I go to the url of the cloud app, I get this error:

[image]

I have gone to the Web.Config file and added:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
<system.web>
```

I re-uploaded the package. That did not help.

I undid that and then found files called web.debug.config and web.release.config with this code in it:

```
<system.web>
<!--
  In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
  <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
  Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
  <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

  <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
    mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
  </customErrors>
-->
  </system.web>
```

I am not really sure if the changing above code helps at all towards anything so I havn't touched it.

I also noticed that when I packaged the Azure Cloud App in Visual Studio (2013) in the output there is a message:

---

Umbrazure.Web(0,0): warning WAT170: The configuration setting 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString' is set up to use the local storage emulator for role 'Umbrazure.Web' in configuration file 'ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg'. To access Microsoft Azure storage services, you must provide a valid Microsoft Azure storage connection string.

---

Would love to hear your thoughts on this problem. I suspect I have either missed something small or, things in Azure have changed a bit since the original code project tutorial was put up.